# Change IE9 Document Mode to IE9 Standards

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, meta

How can I force my IE9 to have the Document Mode of IE9 Standards?

Now, I have this meta content, but it seems it's not working.

```
 <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Also, how can I know if my Document Mode already changed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Suggest using `content="IE=edge"`, which tells it to use the best mode available, rather than `IE=9`, because that would force IE10 into IE9-compat mode.

Comment: By the way - What mode are you actually getting?

Comment: By default, my IE9 is on Browser Mode: IE9 and Document Mode:Quirks, I need the Document Mode to IE9 Standards.tnx

Comment: Quirks mode is the big clue here; you need a doctype rather than the meta tag. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that the browser is defaulting to Quirks mode.

The correct solution to getting out of Quirks mode is to use a DOCTYPE.

Make sure that your HTML code starts with the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should be the first line of code, above the `<html>` tag.

The `X-UA-Compatible` flag is good thing to have, but isn't relevant to your problem in this case. It tells IE to switch between various compatibility modes, but Quirks mode is a whole separate thing, and is controlled by the existence or not of the doctype.

You should keep the `X-UA-Compatible` flag, although as I said in the comments, you would be better to set it to `IE=edge` rather than `IE=9`, otherwise you're going to have problems with IE10 and later.

Hope that helps.

**[EDIT]**

We have now established that the OP's site is running in a frame, inside another site that is in quirks mode.

This is a big problem because IE will render all frames in the same mode, so if the parent site is stuck in quirks mode then his site will also be stuck in quirks mode.

There is pretty much nothing that can be done about this, other than converting one or other site to be in the same mode as the other.

Converting the new code to run in quirks mode might be possible, but is very risky; I would strongly recommend against it. In any case, I would need to spend time studying the whole of your source code before I'd even be able to say whether it's possible or not, let alone how much work it is.

Converting the old code to run in standards mode is likely to be more achieveable. Again, it depends on how large the code base is, but the main point is that you don't need to worry about the conversion breaking due to unsupported features, because the site is already running in an old mode; moving to the newer mode might require some changes, but at least you can be fairly sure from the start that it is possible.

The only other option you have is to change your site so that instead of being in a frame, it pops out into its own separate window (or tab). This way, it can stay in standards mode and the old site can stay in quirks mode. This is the only option you have that doesn't involve a lot of work.

I guess the ultimate message from all of this is that quirks mode is a terrible thing. The world would be a much better place if all those old corporate systems out there running in quirks mode would be upgraded to use standards mode. It really is a lot less effort than people think, and will prevent nasty situations like this one.

Comment: Still no luck,:( I need my document mode to be exactly IE9 Standards. How would I know if my document mode changed? Thanks

Comment: Okay, so you've added a doctype.... what mode does it show now when you load the page?

Comment: With a valid doctype, your page should not be in quirks mode any more. If it *is* still in quirks mode, there may be other serious issues with your HTML; check for HTML errors in the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix anything that comes up there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that my web application is located inside a frameset of our website which is using asp classic. Now, my new web application needs to use IE9 standards. When I we run our application separately, it works, it gets IE9 standards, but when we run it inside our website, it wont work, so I guess that it is using our website document mode instead of the application. Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: @SyntaxError - yes, if it's in a frame, then it will use the parent document's mode. And no, there is nothing you can do about that (other than fixing the parent document, of course). I guess you could pop the new app out into a separate window or tab; would that be a viable work-around?

Comment: ok i guess, we should force our new web application to work in quirks mode. any idea how i can do that?

Comment: I honestly don't think I can help with that. I've spent the last 10 years trying to avoid quirks mode at all costs. Converting to use it is going to be difficult at best. Consider that quirks mode disables a large chunk of the browser features and breaks lots of others; if you're relying on any of those features, you'll have to completely rewrite that code, if it can be done at all. I don't know your code, so I don't know how much work it'll be, but it is quite possible that it might be less work to convert the existing site to use standard mode rather than the other way round.

Comment: (in fact, converting from quirks mode to standard mode is often a lot less work than people think. you might want to consider that as probably your most viable option)

Comment: Thank you very much Spudley..You are such a great help to me to understand my issue. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

use `content="IE=edge"` instead of `IE=9` this will force your IE browser to stick to latest available

Comment: The nature of OP's question is how to force browser into IE9 Standards mode regardless. I am having the same issue and cannot solve it either  using `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `content="IE=9"`.