# SVG in webapp on tomcat6 not working in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tomcat, svg

I have a project with a jsp page containing a little test SVG on a tomcat6 server. It works fine in Firefox, IE10. But in IE9 the SVG don't show up. The funny thing is, when i create the SAME page as html and just open it with IE9 (no tomcat involved) it works fine.

Code in my webapp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <svg id='svg2' width='500' height='500'>
        <rect x="10" y="10" height="300" width="300" style="fill: #000000" id="bot" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

When locking at source code in IE9 /Firefox this shows up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <svg id='svg2' width='500' height='500'>
       <rect x="10" y="10" height="300" width="300" style="fill: #000000" id="bot" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

When i copy this source code in a html file and open it with IE9 the svg shows up correctly.

Can anyone tell me how to get work SVG with tomcat in an IE9?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The Solution was to add following meta tag in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: What mime type are you serving the file as?

Comment: In Firefox its shows "text/html" and in IE9 with right click -> properties the Type = "HTML Document", but not sure if this is the mime type.

Comment: Check that you go into standards mode in IE9, see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015034/change-ie9-document-mode-to-ie9-standards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a content type of `application/xhtml+xml` to convince standards-compliant browsers to render the SVG.

Reference: http://philarcher.org/diary/svgtest/