# App running in a frame inside another site is not compatible with quirks mode

Tags: javascript, java, html, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

My question is very similar to [Change IE9 Document Mode to IE9 Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015034/change-ie9-document-mode-to-ie9-standards).

According to the answer of @Spudley, I most likely could do nothing about this.

But I just hope there could be some work around solution after two years since then.

My app is running in a frame inside a parent site which is hosting a lot of other apps. But my app is not compatible with quirks mode.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<framset>
    <frame name="select" src="">
    <frame name="content" src="">
</framset></html>
```

Updating the parent host site to standard is the last thing I'd like to do because we will need a huge amount of time to test every other single apps.

I wonder if there is any work around, solutions other than pop out a new window for my app?

Please, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

my app works fine with IE10 or above browsers.

Comment: @user4749485 it couldn't run in IE9, I didn't test it with IE8. because the minimum requirement is IE9. my app works fine with IE10 or above browsers

Comment: There has been (and will be) no change.  All frames must be in similar document modes.  Your best bet is to add a link that opens the individual app in question in a separate framing window, one that's in a compatible document mode.